# Calendar and Task synch with Outlook: deprecated in 2016 ver?

Tags: calendar, tasks, 2016, synchronisation, exchange-server

I have a doubt on a paragraph I read on this page

https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/16/whats-new-in-sharepoint-and-project-server-2016-in-simple-words/

In the list of deprecated features at n. 8 it is written

"My Tasks and associated Exchange Task Sync features.They have been removed because the Work Management Service Application that is required for both features has also been removed."

Does this mean that it will no longer possible to 'connect with outlook' from the ribbons of the task list and calendar list?

I am on O356 and it still works or so it seems to me.

Can someone explain the sentence above?

Comment: No, that will still work. The removed feature was a technology that was supposed to automatically gather all your tasks